# How to convert a python file to an executable for Mac, when I don't have a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, executable

I have a Windows computer and I want to make a downloadable executable for a python file I made.
I ran PyInstaller and I got a .exe, because I'm using Windows. So that's good.

How do I make one that is compatible with Mac, with only my Windows computer? I don't have a Mac and I don't know what file type they use for executables either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible, since it's more complex than you think.

But anyway, take a look on:

- [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

If this is not working, try to install some virtual environment on your PC from either:

- [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/sickcodes/docker-osx)
- virtualization tools like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [vmware](https://www.vmware.com/ca.html).

Another way is to search for an online machine, e.g [AWS EC2 with MacOS operating system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html).